# How to Stop constructor of base class to be called in child class

Tags: php, oop

Below is my base class i.e database methods.

```
// Constructor
public function __construct($argHost, $argUsername, $argPassword, $argDatabase)
{
    $this->_host = $argHost;
    $this->_username = $argUsername;
    $this->_password = $argPassword;
    $this->_database = $argDatabase;
}

// Connect to the database
public function Connect()
{
    if (!$this->Is_Connected()) {
        $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this->_host,$this->_username,$this->_password,$this->_database);    
    } else {
        return $this->_connection;
    }

}
// Run query
public function Run($query)
{
    if ($this->result = mysqli_query($this->_connection,$query)) {
        return $this->result;
    } else {
        die("Couldn't perform the request");
    }
}
```

And my child class is categories method below

```
class Categories extends Database
{    
    public $category_id = '';
    public $category_name = '';
    public $category_image = '';

    // View Category
    public function ViewCategories() 
    {
        return $this->Run("SELECT * FROM categories");
    }       
}
```

Now the problem is that when i am running the Run() method by creating object of the base class it is working fine. But when i am creating object object the child class i.e categories and executing the method viewCategories(); i m receiving below errors

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Database::__construct(), called in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\index.php on line 16 and defined in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Database::__construct(), called in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\index.php on line 16 and defined in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for Database::__construct(), called in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\index.php on line 16 and defined in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 17
>
> Warning: Missing argument 4 for Database::__construct(), called in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\index.php on line 16 and defined in
>   E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 35
>   Couldn't perform the request

Udated : This is how i am calling the methods

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    include 'classes/class.'.$class_name . '.php';
}
$connection = new Database("localhost", "raheel", "raheel786", "ecommerce");
$connection->Connect();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Ecommerce</title>
</head>
<body>
   <?php 
   $category = new Categories();
   $category_list = $category->ViewCategories();
   var_dump($category_list);
   ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me how to fix that.

Comment: you aren't passing any params to the constructor

Comment: Define an empty constructor in your child class to override the constructor in the parent class; otherwise rule of inheritance apply and the parent constructor will be called

Comment: I am passing it let me update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to overload constructor. Just add empty `__construct()` method to child class

```
class Categories extends Database{

    public function __construct() {}

    ...

}
```

but it will not solve your problem:)

As a solution i can see 2 variants:

1) make static variable `_connection` so it will be available in all objects

```
public function Connect(){
    if( ! self::$_connection){
        self::$_connection = mysqli_connect($this->_host,$this->_username,$this->_password,$this->_database);    
    }

    return self::$_connection;
}

public function Run($query){
    if($this->result = mysqli_query(self::$_connection,$query)){
    return $this->result;
                }
                else 
                   die("Couldn't perform the request");
}
```

2) I think it is better way. Make 2 independent classes with connect and queries so one will contain another

```
class Database {
    // Constructor
    public function __construct($argHost,$argUsername,$argPassword,$argDatabase){
        $this->_host = $argHost;
        $this->_username = $argUsername;
        $this->_password = $argPassword;
        $this->_database = $argDatabase;
    }

    // Connect to the database
    public function Connect(){
        if(!$this->Is_Connected()){
            $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this->_host,$this->_username,$this->_password,$this->_database);    
        } else {
            return $this->_connection;
        }
    }
    // Run query
    public function Run($query){
        if($this->result = mysqli_query($this->_connection,$query)){
            return $this->result;
        }
        else 
           die("Couldn't perform the request");
    }
}


class Categories extends Database{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public $category_id = '';
    public $category_name = '';
    public $category_image = '';

    // View Category
    public function ViewCategories() {
        return $this->db->Run("SELECT * FROM categories");
    }   
}
```

So usage is:

```
$connection = new Database("localhost", "raheel", "raheel786", "ecommerce");
$connection->Connect();

$category = new Categories($connection);
```

Attention! I didn't test it, just give an example

Comment: I tried this , but by doing this my connection link from the base class which is  protected $_connection; is returning null and i am receiving below error

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in E:\xampplite\htdocs\ecommerce\classes\class.database.php on line 35
Couldn't perform the request

Comment: yes. i just answered your question "how to prevent calling constructor of base class":) there was changes in my answer

Comment: getting your point but what does public function __construct(Database $db) means?

Comment: It means that if you pass not a Database object there will be an error. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Comment: Thank you so much this seems to be useful

Comment: Upvoting can be the best feedback:) was glad to help anyway

Comment: I was trying to check mark your answer but it was not letting me do that :S how can i do it ?

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use inheritance for [has-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a), inheritance describes the [is-a relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). And in your case Categories **is not a** Database, Categories **has a** database.

Use composition instead:

```
class Categories
{
    private $database;

    function __construct(Database $database)
    {
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function ViewCategories()
    {
        return $this->database->Run("SELECT * FROM categories");
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
$connection = new Database("localhost", "raheel", "raheel786", "ecommerce");
$connection->Connect();
// ...
$category = new Categories($connection);
$category_list = $category->ViewCategories();
var_dump($category_list);
```

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing my concept your technique worked Thank you :)